# What is the conditional min-entropy of a pure bipartite state?

Tags: quantum-state, information-theory, entropy, min-entropy

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.1338), it is stated that the conditional min-entropy $H(A|B)_{\rho_{AB}}$ of $A$ conditioned on $B$ for any $\textbf{pure}$ quantum system $\rho_{AB}=|\psi_{AB} \rangle \langle \psi_{AB} |$ is
$$ H_{\textrm{min}}(A|B)_{|\psi_{AB} \rangle \langle \psi_{AB} |} = - \textrm{log}_{2} \Big(\textrm{tr}\sqrt{\rho_{A}} \Big)^{2}\,, $$
where $\rho_{A}:= \textrm{tr}_{A}\rho_{AB}$ and $H_{\textrm{min}}(A|B)_{\rho_{AB}}$ is defined by
$$   H_{\textrm{min}}(A|B)_{\rho_{AB}} := - \inf_{\sigma_B}\, {D}_{\infty}(\rho_{A B} \| \mathbb{I}_A \otimes \sigma_B)\,, $$
where
$$D_{\infty}(\tau\|\tau') :=
   \inf\{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}: \, \tau \leq 2^\lambda \tau' \} \ . $$
The result for pure states is stated without any proof or reference, so I assume it comes straight from the definition, but I haven't been able to derive it. I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-entropy#:%7E:text=The%20conditional%20quantum%20min%2Dentropy,analog%20of%20conditional%20quantum%20entropy.&text=Bob%20to%20system-,.,sampling%20from%20his%20own%20system.) that $H_{\textrm{min}}(A|B)_{\rho_{AB}}$ can be defined via an SDP as
$$ H_{\textrm{min}}(A|B)_{\rho_{AB}} = - \textrm{log}_{2}\, \min_{\sigma_{B}}\, \textrm{tr}\sigma_{B}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \textrm{subject to}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \mathbb{I}_A \otimes \sigma_B - \rho_{AB} \geq 0\,, $$
so the optimal $\sigma_{B}$ must satisfy $\textrm{tr}\,\sigma_{B}= \big(\textrm{tr}\sqrt{\rho_A} \big)^{2}$, but I don't see how to prove this. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use an equivalent definition of the min-entropy
$$
\begin{aligned}
H_{\min}(A|B) = - \log_2 \min& \quad \lambda \\
\mathrm{s.t.}& \quad \rho_{AB} \leq \lambda I_A \otimes \sigma_B \\
& \quad \mathrm{tr}[\sigma_B] = 1 \\
& \quad \sigma_B \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$
The interesting condition is $\rho_{AB} \leq \lambda I_A \otimes \sigma_B$. Let's assume $\sigma_B >0$ is positive definite, I'll leave it as an exercise to show that this also works when things are only positive semidefinite. Then this condition is equivalent to $\sigma_B^{-1/2} \rho_{AB} \sigma_{B}^{-1/2} \leq \lambda I_{AB}$ which is in turn equivalent to $\|\sigma_B^{-1/2} \rho_{AB} \sigma_{B}^{-1/2}\|_{\infty} \leq \lambda$. Thus the above program could be equivalently written as
$$
\begin{aligned}
H_{\min}(A|B) = - \log_2 \min& \quad \|\sigma_{B}^{-1/2} \rho_{AB} \sigma_{B}^{-1/2}\|_{\infty} \\
\mathrm{s.t.}& \quad \mathrm{tr}[\sigma_B] = 1 \\
& \quad \sigma_B \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$

Now from the question we know that $\rho_{AB}$ is pure and hence
$$
\|\sigma_{B}^{-1/2} \rho_{AB} \sigma_{B}^{-1/2}\|_{\infty} = \|\sigma_{B}^{-1/2} |\psi\rangle\langle \psi|_{AB} \sigma_{B}^{-1/2}\|_{\infty} = \langle \psi|\sigma_B^{-1}|\psi\rangle = \mathrm{tr}[\rho_B\sigma_B^{-1}]
$$
Taking $\sigma_B = \frac{\sqrt{\rho_B}}{\mathrm{tr}[\sqrt{\rho_B}]}$ we see this feasible point of the SDP gives the objective value you expected, namely $\mathrm{tr}[\sqrt{\rho_B}]^2$.

To show this is optimal we take a look at the dual problem. We know by strong duality that the they will be equal (see the paper) and so if we can find a feasible point of the dual giving the same objective value then we are done. Note the dual problem can be written as
$$
\begin{aligned}
H_{\min}(A|B) = - \log_2 \max & \quad \mathrm{tr} [\rho_{AB} E_{AB}] \\
& \quad \mathrm{tr}_A [E_{AB}] = I_B \\
& \quad E_{AB} \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$
But now consider the feasible point $E_{AB} =\rho_{B}^{-1/2}\rho_{AB} \rho_{B}^{-1/2} $. Using the assumption in the question that $\rho_{AB} $ is pure we see that
$$
\mathrm{tr} [\rho_{AB} E_{AB}] = \langle \psi|\rho_B^{-1/2}|\psi\rangle \langle \psi|\rho_B^{-1/2}|\psi\rangle = \mathrm{tr} [\rho_B^{1/2}]^2
$$
Which is exactly what we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the max relative entropy satisfies, in general,
$$D_{\rm max}(\rho\|\sigma) = \log \inf\{\eta\ge0:\,\, \rho\le \eta \sigma\}.$$

In particular,
$$D_{\rm max}(\rho\|I\otimes \sigma)=\log \min\{\eta\ge0: \,\, \rho\le \eta( I\otimes \sigma)\},
%= \log \min\{ \operatorname{tr}(Y): \,\, Y\ge0, \,\, \rho\le I\otimes Y \}
\\[20px]
H_{\rm min}(A|B)_\rho
\equiv - \min_\sigma D_{\rm max}(\rho\|I\otimes \sigma) 
 = -\log \min\{\operatorname{tr}(Y): \,\, Y\ge0,\, \rho\le I\otimes Y\}.
$$
These identities are all discussed in details for example in [https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/QIT-notes/](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/QIT-notes/).

---

The above tells us that the task is essentially to find $Y\ge0$ such that $\rho\le I\otimes Y$ that minimises $\operatorname{tr}(Y)$, for some pure bipartite state $|\Psi\rangle$, which we can always write in its Schmidt decomposition as $|\Psi\rangle=\sum_k \sqrt{s_k} |u_k,v_k\rangle$.
Let then $\rho=|\Psi\rangle\!\langle\Psi|$.
I'm pretty sure there is a decent general proof of this, but it's eluding me right now. The following is a pretty ugly way to prove this that works for 2-qubit systems, assuming the solution for $Y$ is diagonal in the basis of the Schmidt decomposition of $|\Psi\rangle$.

We can assume without loss of generality that $|\Psi\rangle=\sqrt{s_0}|00\rangle+\sqrt{s_1}|11\rangle$, as this only amounts to a local change of basis.
Let's also assume the solution corresponds to a diagonal $Y$, meaning $Y=\sum_i Y_{ii} \mathbb{P}_i$, where $\mathbb{P}_i\equiv|i\rangle\!\langle i|$. Clearly, we'd also need to show that this is the case, so this proof is incomplete in this regard.

Using this assumption, our task is to minimise $\operatorname{tr}(Y)=Y_{00}+Y_{11}$ under the constraint $I\otimes Y-\rho\ge0$. Explicitly, this amounts to the condition
$$\begin{pmatrix}
Y_{00} -s_0 & 0 & 0 & -\sqrt{s_0 s_1} \\
0 & Y_{11} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & Y_{00} & 0 \\
-\sqrt{s_0 s_1} & 0 & 0 & Y_{11} - s_1
\end{pmatrix} \ge 0.$$
Using Sylvester's criterion, this is equivalent to the set of conditions
$$Y_{00} \ge s_0, \qquad Y_{11} \ge s_1, \qquad Y_{00} Y_{11} \ge s_0 Y_{11} + s_1 Y_{00} .
$$
Given that we need to minimise $Y_{00}+Y_{11}$ under these constraints, we can focus on the last constraint and use Lagrange's multipliers, obtaining the condition
$$Y_{11} -s_1 = Y_{00}-s_0.$$
Putting this condition back into the constraint, we get the following equation for $Y_{00}$:
$$Y_{00}(Y_{00}+s_1-s_0) \ge s_0 (Y_{00}+s_1-s_0) + s_1 Y_{00} \\
\iff Y_{00}^2 - 2s_0 Y_{00} + s_0 (s_0-s_1) \ge 0 \\
\implies Y_{00} \ge s_0 + \sqrt{s_0 s_1} \,\,\vee\,\, Y_{00} \le s_0 - \sqrt{s_0 s_1}.$$
Remembering we must also have $Y_{00}\ge s_0$, we see that only the first condition is in our feasible set. Thus using $Y_{00}=s_0+\sqrt{s_0 s_1}$, the relation found above between $Y_{00}$ and $Y_{11}$, and $s_0+s_1=1$, we conclude that the trace is given by
$$\operatorname{tr}(Y) = Y_{00} + Y_{11} =
2Y_{00} + s_1 - s_0 =
1 + 2\sqrt{s_0 s_1}. $$

This corresponds to the result stated in terms of $[\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt\rho_A)]^2$, because $\sqrt{\rho_A}=\sqrt{s_0} \mathbb{P}_0+\sqrt{s_1} \mathbb{P}_1$, hence
$$[\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt\rho_A)]^2 =
(\sqrt{s_0}+\sqrt{s_1})^2 = 1 + 2 \sqrt{s_0 s_1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Reading again the paper you linked, I think the way the authors were thinking about the result was of showing this via the relations between conditional min- and max-entropies, see discussion at the end of section A, page 2 in the [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.1338).
This is clearly a much more elegant and general way to show the result, and completely different from the other approach, so I'm posting it as a different answer.

1. Given any bipartite $\rho\equiv\rho_{AB}$, consider a purification $\rho_{ABC}$ on some auxiliary purification space $C$, and define the conditional max-entropy as
   $$H_{\rm max}(A|B)_\rho \equiv - H_{\rm min}(A|C)_\rho.$$
2. Observe that for product states, $\rho = \rho_A\otimes\rho_B$, we have
   $$H_{\rm min}(A|B)_\rho = -\log\min\{\operatorname{tr}(Y): \,\, Y\ge0,\,\rho_A\otimes\rho_B\le I\otimes Y\}
   \\= -\log\min\{\alpha: \,\,\alpha\ge0,\,\, \rho_A\le \alpha\}
   = -\log\|\rho_A\|_\infty \equiv H_{\rm min}(A)_{\rho_A},$$
   where in the last 2 steps we observed that the $Y$ that saturates the inequality will have the form $Y=\alpha\rho_B$ for some $\alpha=\operatorname{tr}(Y)$.

   To compute $H_{\rm max}(A|B)_\rho$, we can use Lemmas 5,6, and Theorem 3 of the [paper you linked](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.1338), where the authors prove that
   $$H_{\rm max}(A|B)_\rho = \log d_A + \log \max_{\sigma_B} F(\rho,\tau_A\otimes\sigma_B)^2,$$
   where $\tau_A\equiv I_A/d_A$ is the maximally mixed state, and $F(A,B)\equiv\|\sqrt A\sqrt B\|_1$ is the fidelity. In the case of $\rho=\rho_A\otimes\rho_B$, the fidelity is clearly maximal when $\sigma_B=\rho_B$, and thus we get
   $$H_{\rm max}(A|B)_\rho = \log d_A + \log F(\rho_A,I_A/d_A)^2, \\
   F(\rho_A,I_A/d_A) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{d_A}}\|\sqrt{\rho_A}\|_1
   = \operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{\rho_A})/\sqrt{d_A}.$$
   Putting these together you get
   $$H_{\rm max}(A|B)_\rho = H_{\rm max}(A)_{\rho_A} = \log (\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{\rho_A}))^2
   = 2\log \operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{\rho_A}).$$
3. We conclude using the complementary relations that if $\rho=\rho_{AB}$ is pure,
   $$H_{\rm min}(A|B)_\rho = -H_{\rm max}(A|C)_\rho,$$
   where $C$ is a trivial (one-dimensional) space, and therefore
   $$H_{\rm max}(A|C)_\rho = H_{\rm max}(A)_{\rho_A} = 2\log\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{\rho_A}),$$
   which is the result we wanted.